# How to associate work item with check in when using tf.exe

Tags: tfs, changeset, tfs-power-tools

We have a rule in TFS that requires all checkins to be associated with a work item. We have an automated daily build process that uses tf.exe to check in the files. However, I did not find any way to associate files with a work item.
I heard of tfpt, and have it installed, however, I did  not have any success using it to associate files with a changeset either. 
Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure tf.exe / tfpt.exe cannot do this except through their UI.  If you need to use the -noprompt parameter for automation then you're likely out of luck.

Luckily, it's not hard to use the API directly.  [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139040.aspx).  Basically just build up an array of WorkItemCheckinInfo[] and pass it along with your request.

Answer (score -1):

Team Foundation Power Tools has a command for dealing with work items.

```
tfpt.exe help workitem
```

Comment: This is only for creating, updating workitems. Not for associating workitems to a checkin.